# Using Tsurgeon for recursive stripping of phrases

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to "simplify" phrases by recursively stripping modifiers. For example, given a tree with two embedded PPs

```
(NP (NP (JJ Microbial) (NN expression)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN rhizosphere)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNS willows))))))
```

I want to derive first

```
(NP (NP (JJ Microbial) (NN expression)) (PP (IN in) (NP (NP (DT the) (NN rhizosphere)))))
```

and second

```
(NP (NP (JJ Microbial) (NN expression)))
```

However, a script like this

```
PP=pp !<< PP

delete PP
```

will delete both PPs right away, because after the first match, Tsurgeon will immediately apply the same pattern again.

Is there a way to force Tsurgeon to apply the operation only once or is there some other trick to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it in two steps:

1. Mark the required node for deletion.

Like this:

```
PP=pp !<< PP !<< DELETE_ME
relabel pp DELETE_ME
```

2. Delete all marked nodes.

Simply:

```
DELETE_ME=pp
delete pp
```